# How do I model the viewing history of users?

Tags: cassandra

I need to model a history service, where user sees videos.
Service should store a last viewed moment/point-in-time for each video, so if he quit watching we could resume watching from here.
And we also need to be able to show the user's browsing history.

So Q1 is "get a PIT by user and video"

Q2 - "get videos by user and ORDER BY PIT DESC and limit this list with some last records".

For Q1 I've created the table pit_by_user_video (and I would be happy with her - there is just 1 row for user+video, but sorting!):

```sql
CREATE TABLE pit_by_user_video (
  user_id UUID,
  video_id UUID,
  pit timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY((user_id, video_id))
);
```

And I'm unable to create good table for Q2. If for example I try somethins like

```sql
CREATE TABLE pit_by_user_video (
  user_id UUID,
  video_id UUID,
  pit timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, pit, video_id)
);
```

I get a whole series of entries for one video and I still unable to create adequate browsing history.

Any recommendations please?

Comment: No disrespect to those who voted to close this post as "opinion-based" but it is incorrect. There is only one correct answer to the question and is not subject to opinions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The first application query you posted doesn't make sense to me because it doesn't seem to offer anything valuable. Knowing the time a person watched a video has no valid use so I suspect you're doing it to perform another lookup of sorts.

If however you wanted to know how much a user has already watched, then you have the right idea. I would modify the table slightly by using CQL `time` instead because `timestamp` is the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch which is not relevant to your use case.

```
CREATE TABLE watch_time_by_user (
    user_id uuid,
    video_id uuid,
    watched time,
    PRIMARY KEY((user_id, video_id)
)
```

You can get the amount of time watched with this query:

```
SELECT watched FROM watch_time_by_user
WHERE user_id = ?
AND video_id = ?
```

For the second app query, you just need to cluster the videos by the date when the user watched them sorted in descending order:

```
CREATE TABLE watched_by_user (
    user_id uuid,
    date_watched timestamp,
    video_id uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, date_watched)
) CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date_watched DESC)
```

Here's an example for retrieving the last 5 videos watched by a user:

```
SELECT video_id FROM watched_by_user
WHERE user_id = ?
LIMIT 5
```

The result will be a list of videos ordered by the date/time when the user watched them. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you a lot! The key idea is log into 'watched_by_user' table just start of view and not log any progres.